# jenkinsfile use sshUserPrivateKey get auth fail error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

in the jenkinsfile,I want to use privateKey to connect server,but get auth fail error.

```
def remoteConfig = [:]
remoteConfig.name = "my-remote-server"
remoteConfig.host = "${REMOTE_HOST}"
remoteConfig.allowAnyHosts = true

node {
  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
    credentialsId: "${REMOTE_CRED}",
    keyFileVariable: "privateKeyFilePath",
    passphraseVariable: '', usernameVariable: 'rocky'
  )]) {

    remoteConfig.user = "${REMOTE_USER_NAME}"
    remoteConfig.identityFile = privateKeyFilePath

    stage("ssh") {

    
        sh """
            ssh \
              -p 22 \
              -i ${privateKeyFilePath} \
              ${REMOTE_USER_NAME}@${REMOTE_HOST} \
              'echo Hello World!'
          """

      sshCommand remote: remoteConfig, command: 'for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done'

    }
  }
}
```

but get this error

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
```

seem like the sshCommand has bug,but not sure

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be that you want to use a private key stored in some path on disk, but in your script you're using `withCredentials` to read the private key from jenkins store.

If you have the private key in a path file, not use `withCredentials` instead try using `identityFile` to specify the private key file path and `passphrase` for the private key file password in `remote`, as defined in the documentation https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin :

```java
node {
  def remoteConfig = [:]
  remoteConfig.name = 'my-remote-server'
  remoteConfig.host = "${REMOTE_HOST}"
  remoteConfig.allowAnyHosts = true
  remoteConfig.user = "${REMOTE_USER_NAME}"
  remoteConfig.identityFile = privateKeyFilePath
  remoteConfig.passphrase = 'privateKeyPassword'
  stage('Remote SSH') {
    sshCommand remote: remoteConfig, command: 'for i in {1..5}; do echo -n "Loop \$i"; date ; sleep 1; done'

  }
}
```